# How do i order by Date Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have some entries in a database and and they all contain a date string.

I have some TS like this

```
ref.LimitToFirst(10).orderByChild('date')
```

The problem i an having is that TS treats this as a regular string and just orders by the first number in the date. ex - 10/1/2021 would be ordered before 2/1/2021. How could i fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix this in code while depending on the database to perform the query.  In Realtime Database, strings will always sort lexicographically - by their natural string order.  You can't make it interpret the strings as something other than a normal string.

You will have to instead store an integer value that you can sort chronologically.  In JavaScript, you can simply create a Date object and use its [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method field to get the Date's representation in millis since the unix epoch.

If you can't store a proper timestamp, then your only option is to read all the data and sort it yourself in your app, which will not scale well.

Comment: Is there any way to sort the arrays in revers when using ngFor ? . That, way i get the last object to stay at the top ?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately.